# Deleting files on sdcard?

Tags: android, sd-card, delete-file

I've been trying to delete files on sdcard using the following code, but it is not working.
 Here's the context menu showing the option to delete, but when I press it nothing happens, by the way, "pass" is a directory is created on sdcard by my app:

```
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {  
            super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo); 
                menu.setHeaderTitle("Context Menu");  
                menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "delete");  
                menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "wtever");  
            }  


        @Override  
        public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {  
            if(item.getTitle()=="delete"){function1(item.getItemId());}  
            else if(item.getTitle()=="wtever"){function2(item.getItemId());}  
            else {return false;}  
        return true;  
        }  

        public void function1(int id){  
            Toast.makeText(this, "function 1 called", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
            File folder = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            String fileName = folder.getPath() + "/pass/hello.pdf";

            File myFile = new File(fileName);
            if(myFile.exists())
                myFile.delete();

        }
```

// the list class

```
 public class PDFListActivity extends ListActivity {
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
            int clickCounter=0;
            ArrayList<String> listItems=new ArrayList<String>();
            private File[] imagelist;
            String[] pdflist;


        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.mainlistpdf);
              File images=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "pass");
                imagelist = images.listFiles(new FilenameFilter(){  
                        public boolean accept(File dir, String name)  
                        {    

                                return ((name.endsWith(".pdf")));  
                        }  
                });

                pdflist = new String[imagelist.length];
                for(int i = 0;i<imagelist.length;i++)
                {
                        pdflist[i] = imagelist[i].getName();
                }
                this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, pdflist));
                ListView list=getListView();
                registerForContextMenu(list);
        }
```

Comment: can you have log and check whether function1 is called or not?/

Comment: yes it is called. I get the toast message  "function 1 called"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this [LINK](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#context-menu) to create custom context menu and place your menus file in res/menu folder.

or try replacing the below code

```
File folder = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
String fileName = folder.getPath() + "/pass/hello.pdf";
```

with

```
 String fileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/pass/hello.pdf";
```

Comment: it works finally,but I have to refresh the list,I mean is I don't see the file being deleted, I have to call the function again

Comment: so it was deleted but was still visible on menu list?

Comment: if so, you must refresh the list to take effects.

Comment: could you tell me how to refresh the list?

Comment: can you post code for how you display list then i can tell accordingly

Comment: if you using custom adapter then you a method call notifydatachanged() you have use it

Comment: ok, I got it appreciate your help :).. by the way I called that activity again `startActivity(new Intent("android.intent.action.PDFListACTIVITY"));`

Answer (score 1):

Use the below code to delete all file and the directory from sdcard::

```
public static boolean deleteDirectory(File path) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if( path.exists() ) {
            File[] files = path.listFiles();
            for(int i=0; i<files.length; i++) {
                if(files[i].isDirectory()) {
                    deleteDirectory(files[i]);
                }
                else {
                    files[i].delete();
                }
            }
        }
        return(path.delete());
    }
```

Comment: ty in advanced , but I don't want to delete the directory only a specific file, I mean the file you press on

Comment: then remove path.delete() from above code that will delete all the files in directory

Comment: and if you want to delete only single file the use files.delete();

Comment: I've used it in my posted code above, but not working, would you have a look at the public void function1